# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp64\www\web\db.php on line 3

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, connection

> ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp64\www\web\db.php on line 3

Call Stack

```
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0840  407896  {main}( )   ...\registration.php:0
2   0.0850  408192  require( 'C:\wamp64\www\web\db.php' )   ...\registration.php:73
3   0.0850  408192  mysqli_connect ( )  ...\db.php:3
```

> Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Everything look ok, but still getting problem in connection with phpmyadmin.

Comment: What server are you using? Have you tried using your IP address instead of localhost? Also it would be better if you posted your connection code here also.

Comment: Please provide us with your code:-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using WAMP. WAMP's default user is `root` and the password is *blank* (unless you had changed it). You're connecting to MySQL with a password (see `using password: YES`), it needs to be `using password: NO`; meaning logging in with a *blank* (`''`) password. In `\db.php:3` rewrite the MySQL password for `mysqli_connect` with `''` and try again.